# google Shortener Url Tracking to developer account

Tags: ios, google-api

I am creating new IOS App that uses google shortener if user log in using OAuth he can track created url but in my App we don't have google log in we preferred not have many log in's ,but i want to track
user created url with using only google Api key. user is not log in it can't map to user at least it can track by developer .Any help appreciated.

Comment: You want to track the URL Analytics and creating goo.gl URLs without getting logged in by the user?

Comment: @Rajan Balana Thanks for replay,i want to create an App using that user creates url's,i want to track url's those are created in my App

Comment: Yes, You cannot do that without authenticating the user, You have to go with the login option.

Comment: if i provide the OAuth log in user created url's are adding to currently logged in user.i want add those url's to developers account .

Comment: @RajanBalana Thanks for your replay i edited the question check once .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check this link https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started
in this you can found complete information about shorter api

Sorry it is not possible to add url's for developer account .